# Stop SQL Server services from conveniently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a general use laptop.  I use it for games, development, and web surfing.  I've just installed SQL Server 2008 with Analysis, Reporting, and Error reporting, as well as any of the other options on the installer.

I also have a default instance of SQL server as well as a named instance.

When I'm not doing development, I'd like to shut down these services conveniently.  I'm thinking that a batch file would be good.  What are the commands to shut these services down and release the associated memory and resources?

It appears that:

```
net stop MSSQLSERVER
```

seems to stop the MSSQLSERVER instance.  What about the other services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as for any other service, you can use either the Service name or the Display name as it appears in the services configuration (Administrative Tools->Services):

[image]

```
net stop "SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
```

or

```
net stop MSSQLServerOLAPService
```

Comment: Also from PowerShell you can use `Stop-Service`. Put the commands in a couple of scripts to make starting and stopping as a group easier (this would also allow you to wait for dependent services -- like Agent -- to stop before stopping the dependency).